# If statement in R executing a false statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I am new to R. I have a condition which is false

```
> mydata[[1,7]]==3.0
[1] FALSE
```

However, when I use 'if condition' on it, the statement under the if condition gets executed even when it is a false condition. Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Code-

```
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), lsf.str()))
mydata = read.table("path/file",header = TRUE);

if(mydata[[1,7]]==3.0)          #false statement
  {
  brit_W1<-mydata[[1,5]]        
  }
```

Console-

```
> brit_W1
[1] 333
```

I have checked this with the debugger too (which indicates that the statement under if is being executed). I cleared all the variables several times to delete previous values, but of no use.

My data

```
GRID    I    J    K      BRITTSME      SWETSMEB      USERPROR
ROOT    1    1    1      333.000         56.000         0.000
```

Comment: If you `rm(bw_W1)`, then run your `if` block surely, surely `brit_W1` won't be assigned unless your `mydata[1,3]` is equal to 3?

Comment: This is not reproducible. Show us something we can work with.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I run your code using your data, I get the expected result, namely that `brit_W1` is not assigned.

Comment: @joran, dont know whats wrong. Have already spent like 3 hours on this.

Comment: Well, now you have verification that in a clean R session, this all works just fine. So that would suggest that whatever attempts you've made at this, they have likely _not_ been in a clean, fresh R session, despite what you may have thought.

Comment: does the execution of the the statement under the if statement in the debug mode in R indicates it is being executed (like matlab)? I just tried again from scratch and it seems that brit_W1 is no more being assigned, however the debugger still indicates that the statement is executed (though nothing actually happens).

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "debug mode" since the example code you provided is not in a function. When I wrap the code in a function and debug the function, I see no indication that that line is run. I also do not see any indication that that line is run when setting a breakpoint in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I think, just clean all locally created objects using `rm(list=ls())` and then run again. If problem persist, please specify your data frame also.

You can always see these objects using `ls()`. If you just want to delete some of the objects (a,b and c) then do `rm(a,b,c)`

Comment: Yes clearing the created objects was my first thought too. Please see the edited question. The problem still persists.

Comment: On my system there is no problem.                                     output of 'brit_W1' is "
Error: object 'brit_W1' not found"